# 3D Plotting for the solution of stochastic differential equation

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, stochastic-calculus

I have the following solution  of the SDE:
$$U(x,t)=-6+12 * \tanh \left[x+\left(B(t)-\frac{t^{2}}{2}\right)+\int_{0}^{t} e^{s^{2}} d s\right]^{2}$$

Where $B(t)$ is white noise.

In the following code and Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSn66.png), the solution is drawn without noise

```
Plot3D[-6 + 12*Tanh[x + (0 - t^2/2) + \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(t\)]\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), 
SuperscriptBox[\(s\), \(2\)]] \[DifferentialD]s\)\)]^2, {t, 0, 
  4}, {x, -4, 4}]
```

[image: With out noise]

In the following code and Figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiqrC.png), the solution is drawn with  noise

```
tmax = 10;
samplesPerSec = 10;
ω = 2;
σ = 1;
noise = Interpolation[
   Normal[RandomFunction[
      WhiteNoiseProcess[σ], {0, tmax*samplesPerSec}]][[1]]];

Plot3D[-6 + 12*Tanh[x + (noise[t*samplesPerSec] - t^2/2) + \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\), \(0\), \(t\)]\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), 
SuperscriptBox[\(s\), \(2\)]] \[DifferentialD]s\)\)]^2, {t, 0, 
  4}, {x, -4, 4}]
```

[image: With Noise]

**The question is how can I get a figure that contains more noise as in Figure [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mOZn.png)**
[image: Example With noise]

**Is there a better way to add more Noise to the solution and draw it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can replace the integral in the plot with `1/2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Erfi[t]` - it will be faster and it will let you increase the sample rate.
2. You can increase the `PlotPoints` to get a better plot.
3. Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think you don't need `WhiteNoiseProcess` here - you can just draw from a `NormalDistribution` directly.

```
σ = 1;
Plot3D[-6 + 12*Tanh[x + (RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, σ]] - t^2/2) + 1/2 Sqrt[π]Erfi[t]]^2,
  {t, 0, 4}, {x, -4, 4}, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotTheme -> "Classic"]
```

[image: stochastic diff eqn solution]